# Как делать, чтобы программа определила на какую кнопку нажали

Tags: java, android

Создаю игру "Крестики-нолики". Есть 4 Activity: на Activity1 есть 2 кнопки "new game" и  "exit". На Activity2 выбор 1 игрок или 2 игрока. На Activity3 выбор играть крестиком или ноликом. На Activity4 сама игра.

Вопрос такой: я эти кнопки, точнее их нажатие, сохранил в `SharedPreferences`. На Activity4 где игра, я получаю данные, но проверки выбранных значений работают неправильно.

**Activity2**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    buttonplayer1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.player1);
    buttonplayer2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.player2);

    buttonplayer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            player1();
        }
    });

    buttonplayer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            player2();
        }
    });
}

public void player1(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("play1", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("player1", "string1");
    editor.apply();
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void player2(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("play2", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("player2", "string2");
    editor.apply();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Activity3**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
    buttonx = (Button)findViewById(R.id.x);
    buttono = (Button)findViewById(R.id.o);

    buttonx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            x();
        }
    });

    buttono.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            o();
        }
    });
}

public void x(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main3Activity.this, Main4Activity.class);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("playx", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("playerx", "stringx");
    editor.apply();
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void o(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main3Activity.this, Main4Activity.class);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("playo", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("playero", "stringo");
    editor.apply();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Activity4**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);
    btn8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8);
    btn9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn9);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("play1", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String player1 = sharedPreferences1.getString("player1", "string1");

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2 = getSharedPreferences("play2", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String player2 = sharedPreferences2.getString("player2", "string2");

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesx = getSharedPreferences("playx", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String playerx = sharedPreferencesx.getString("playerx", "stringx");

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferenceso = getSharedPreferences("playo", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String playero = sharedPreferenceso.getString("playero", "stringo");

    if (player1.equals("string1") && playerx.equals("stringx")) {
        btn1.setText("X");
    }
    if (player1.equals("string1") && playero.equals("stringo")) {
        btn1.setText("O");
    }
    if (player2.equals("string2") && playerx.equals("stringx")){
        btn2.setText("X");
    }
    if(player2.equals("string2") && playero.equals("stringo")){
        btn2.setText("O");
    }}
```

Как сделать, чтобы программа знала, какие кнопки были нажаты?

Comment: `но на activity где игра, я получаю данные sharedpreferences а, просто не знаю че работает.` что тут написано?

Comment: На 3 и 4 activity создаю sharedpreferences, а на 4 получаю их значение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь писать каждое выбранное значения в отдельные `SharedPreferences` (SP) с разными ключами для каждого значения. Соответственно, при чтении, если значение выбранно не было, то берётся дефолтное.

Например, пользователь выбрал `string1` (записалось в SP `play1`) и `stringo` (записалось SP `playo`). При чтении вы получите

> player1 = string1 - OK
>
> player2 = string2 - так как значение выбранно не было, взято дефолтное
>
> playerx = stringx - так как значение выбранно не было, взято дефолтное
>
> playero = stringo - OK

В итоге при проверке у вас выполняются все условия по очереди.

**Что же делать?** Писать все значения в одни SP, в которых будет всего два ключа "player" (1 или 2) и "role" (X или O).

Пример для "role" ( для "player" то же самое, только со своим ключём):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SP", MODE_PRIVATE);

buttonx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        selectRole("x");
    }
});

buttono.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        selectRole("o");
    }
});

public void selectRole(String role){
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("role", role).apply();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main3Activity.this, Main4Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Ну и читать значения так:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SP", MODE_PRIVATE);
String player = sharedPreferences.getString("player", "1");
String role = sharedPreferences.getString("role", "x");
```

Советую обязательно разобраться и понять написанное, а не просто переписать код. Для этого старался объяснить максимально понятно.

Comment: Спс большое, вот и моя проблема была в этом

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйся фрагментами, а не активити и самое банальное решение - сделать так:
когда открываешь 3 фрагмент с выбором х или о, делаешь в нем сеттер

```
public void setQuantityPlayer(int quantity){
this.quantityPlayer = quantity;
}
```

и вызываешь этот метод при создании 3тего фрагмента.
в 4том фрагменте создаешь такой же сеттер только с еще одним параметор

```
  public void setQuantityPlayer(int quantity, String xOrO){
    this.quantityPlayer = quantity;
    this.xOrO = xOrO;
    }
```

и вызываешь этот сеттер когда создаешь 4тый фрагмент, передавая значения которые у тебя есть в третьем

вот гайды по фрагментам 
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragments.php

Comment: Но если мне нужно делать с activity, то как делать?

Comment: Подключай бд сохраняй локально, либо каждый раз перезаписывай интенты. Получил инфу с интента, перезаписал ее для следующей активити и т.д. Но делать все через активити не особо профитно